# Why do i get an Invalid route error in cp when calling plugin action?

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, routes

I have a plugin that has a menu and in backend which basically has a button that calls the plugins default controller actionXXXX method.

The action does some database / api work then is meant to return a result in a results template.

I have no idea how plugins got so complicated in craft and Im about ready to give up after today. The plugin main file supplies EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES

```
 Event::on(
            UrlManager::class,
            UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES,
            function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
                $event->rules['mapit-api2entry/default/map-it'] = 'results';
            }
        );
```

The plugin form in the cp has a hidden action like so. Do I need admin here? I assume so because we are in the CP.

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="admin/actions/mapit-api2entry/default/map-it">
```

I can put the url "admin/actions/mapit-api2entry/default/map-it" in the browser and pull up my template as expected.

But when I hit the submit button I get:

```
Unable to resolve the request "admin/actions/mapit-api2entry/default/map-it".
```

How do I tell the plugin / cp the right route to use after the action is triggered? Is this case of camel -vs kebab somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [my other answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/38324/4169) is also part of this one.

The only specifics I'd add here is that your action is getting "double-declared," in a way. Using the `action` param in a request has a lot of weight in Craft's eye—but you're stacking two strategies, and the system can't match it with your intent.

My recommendation is (whenever possible) to use Craft's Twig helpers:

```
<form method="POST">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    {{ actionInput('mapit-api2entry/default/map-it') }}

    <button>Go!</button>
</form>
```

This will generate a hidden `action` input that looks like this:

```html
<input name="action" value="mapit-api2entry/default/map-it">
```

Notice that we don't declare `action` as part of the route! Craft already knows you want to route directly to a Controller/Action path because it sees the `action` param.

The direct-access behavior you see is a vanity/convenience feature—the [`actionTrigger`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#actiontrigger) (the first segment in that path, aside from the [`cpTrigger`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#cptrigger)—`admin` by default) is actually customizable, and not particularly useful in my mind, when the Twig helpers (and `action` query/POST param) are so reliable.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.(lovely work by the way )
Finally got a result.
So is there no need to tell craft that this is a cptrigger - is this done in the route?   $event->rules['mapit-api2entry/default/map-it'] = 'results';
And or in the controller? Eg $this->renderTemplate('xxx')

Comment: Keep in mind that the "key" you assign to the `rules` array is the alias to your controller action, and the "value" (what is assigned) is the full controller path: `$event->rules['my-shortcut-route'] = 'mapit-api2entry/default/map-it';`, where `DefaultController::actionMapIt()` becomes available at `my-shortcut-route` (or `admin/my-shortcut-route`, if you're in the CP). I'm not entirely sure how the determinations of an "Action Request" and a "CP Request" overlap—but generally, actions are for logic + processing, and they redirect to an `admin/my-route` in success/fail states.