# Can some one explain Event rules in plugins

Tags: craft3, plugin-development, routes

So here is what I see in a controller:

```
 $event->rules['cpActionTrigger1'] = 'plugin/default/do-something';
```

What does the first part 'cpActionTrigger1' refer to and what does the second part refer to. I am guessing route and template but never see it spelled out in docs.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it’d be in a closure registered on the `UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES` event, like this:

```php
Event::on(
    UrlManager::class,
    UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES,
    function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $e) {
        $e->rules['my/route'] => 'module/controller/action';
    });
```

The above explains it almost in context—when creating a route with a plain string, it's interpreted as:

```
<module-id>/<controller-name>/<action-name>
```

The "Module ID" is either defined by the Plugin in question, or when you declare modules in `app.php`:

```php
<?php

return [
    '*' => [
        // Lots of other irrelevant (but important) stuff redacted, here!
        'modules' => [
            'bizniz' => \modules\mymodule\BusinessStuff::class,
        ],
     ],
];
```

If you had a Controller in your Module (and have [properly declared `BusinessStuff::$controllerNamespace`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-application#$controllerNamespace-detail)) that looked like this…

```php
<?php

namespace modules\mymodule\controllers;

use craft\base\Controller;

class FinanceController extends Controller
{
    public function actionCountBeans()
    {
        return $this->asJson(['profit' => (rand() / getrandmax()) * 1000000]);
    }
}
```

…your "action path" would be `bizniz/finance/count-beans`. Yii takes care of mapping the path to your controller—and the `UrlManager` ensures the key you assign it to acts as an alias.